# primeng p-datatable two way binding issue in angular 4

Tags: primeng-datatable

i have a data table as shown below(using primeng datatable)

```
<p-dataTable   [value]="gridData" [editable]="true"   >
<p-header>Extraction Fields Setup</p-header>
<p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" 
[sortable]="true" [editable]="col.edit" [style]="{'overflow': 
'visible','width':''}">
</p-column>
<p-footer>
<div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="width:100%"><button type="button" 
pButton icon="fa-plus" style="float:left" label="Add" 
(click)="showDialogToAdd()">Add</button>
</div>
</p-footer>
</p-dataTable>
```

when click on Add in Footer i fired an event showDialogToAdd() code as shown below.

```
    let newBatchObj = {};
    newBatchObj['extractionType'] = '11';
    newBatchObj['fieldname'] = '1';
    newBatchObj['fielddata'] = '1';
    newBatchObj['Anchor'] = '1';
    newBatchObj['bRules'] = '1';
    this.gridData.push(newBatchObj);
```

but p-datatable was not showing the newly added value

Answer (score 1):

you can resolve your problem changing the attribute immutable to false. So your HTML should be like following:

```
<p-dataTable [immutable]="false" [value]="gridData" [editable]="true">
// your code...
</p-dataTable>
```

I've found the solution on: [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472529/angular-primeng-cannot-binding-data-by-customer-list)

More details on: [PrimeNG documentations](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

> this.gridData = [...this.gridData,newBatchObj];

using `...` (Spread operator) to avoid mutating objects.