# Angular Primeng cannot binding data by customer list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a rest api to get data, like as

```
async getAllTrainingClass(): Promise<void>{
     await this.traningClassService.getListTrainingClass().then(data 
      =>this.listTraining = data);
}
```

try to show data on html, it's OK:

```
<p-dataTable  [value]="listTraining" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true">
            .....
        </p-dataTable>
```

But I try to use the customer array, like as:

```
listData:MyClass[] = new Array<MyClass>();
```

and push data

```
this.listData.push(this.item);
```

on console.log the listData has 2 item, but when biding to html, data does not display.

```
<p-dataTable  [value]="listData" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true">
            .....
        </p-dataTable>
```

please advice me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[immutable]="false"`

```
<p-dataTable [immutable]="false" [value]="listData" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true">

</p-dataTable>
```